# Launch screen storyboard: Split View Controller shows incorrect master/detail relationship

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios9, xcode-storyboard

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Xcode 7.1, iOS 9.1. A launch screen storyboard includes a Split View Controller as the Initial View Controller, with a master connection to a View Controller (wrapped in a Navigation Controller) and a detail connection to another View Controller (also wrapped in a Navigation Controller). The storyboard is code-less, as the application itself manages its UI programmatically. The storyboard is being implemented only for iOS 9 multitasking compatibility.

**PROBLEMS:**

1.) When launching the storyboard on an iPad Simulator in the portrait orientation, only the detail View Controller appears, covering the master View Controller. The application forces both master and detail (side-by-side) in-code not only in landscape, but also in portrait.

How can a storyboard imitate such behavior?

2.) When launching the storyboard on an iPad Simulator in the landscape orientation, both master and detail View Controllers are visible properly, but the master View Controller is too narrow, as if the iPad Simulator were in the portrait orientation. (In the landscape orientation, a master View Controller is supposed to be somewhat wider than - the same - master View Controller in the portrait orientation.)

Is this a bug with the Simulator?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you make progress there?

Comment: You could create a slimmed down version of your custom `UISplitViewController` as a new class called `LaunchViewController`. This wouldn't have any code related to data but would have the same logic regarding the UI appearance. Use this class in `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. I am yet to try it

Comment: Closest I could find an answer to this is doing this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/30451 pretty involved and not worth it in my case since the only difference between the starting left and right is the line down the middle but passing along for others that have different backgrounds for master and detail

Comment: @user1046037: no, as of Xcode 9, iOS 11: `LaunchScreen.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: Launch screens may not set custom classnames` and `LaunchScreen.storyboard: Launch screens may not use user defined runtime attributes` for `UISplitViewController` `preferredDisplayMode`.